# How to Display Opencart 3 Postcode in Twig

Tags: twig, opencart

How to display postcode only in Opencart version 3 using twig?

I tried to customize `/admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.twig`:

```
{% for order in orders %}

{{ order.shipping_address }}
{{ order.telephone }}
{{ order.store_telephone }}
{{ order.shipping_postcode }} <!-- This one doesn't work -->

{% endfor %}
```

`{{ order.shipping_postcode }}` line doesn't work. The rest is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Postcode is displayed in the address:

[image]

But if you want to output separately, then you need to work with the controller.

Search In `\admin\controller\sale\order.php` in `public function shipping() {`:

```
$data['orders'][] = array(
                    'order_id'         => $order_id,
                    'invoice_no'       => $invoice_no,
                    'date_added'       => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])),
                    'store_name'       => $order_info['store_name'],
                    'store_url'        => rtrim($order_info['store_url'], '/'),
                    'store_address'    => nl2br($store_address),
                    'store_email'      => $store_email,
                    'store_telephone'  => $store_telephone,
                    'email'            => $order_info['email'],
                    'telephone'        => $order_info['telephone'],
                    'shipping_address' => $shipping_address,
                    'shipping_method'  => $order_info['shipping_method'],
                    'product'          => $product_data,
                    'comment'          => nl2br($order_info['comment'])
                );
```

Adding:

```
$data['orders'][] = array(
                    'order_id'         => $order_id,
                    'invoice_no'       => $invoice_no,
                    'date_added'       => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])),
                    'store_name'       => $order_info['store_name'],
                    'store_url'        => rtrim($order_info['store_url'], '/'),
                    'store_address'    => nl2br($store_address),
                    'store_email'      => $store_email,
                    'store_telephone'  => $store_telephone,
                    'email'            => $order_info['email'],
                    'telephone'        => $order_info['telephone'],
                    'shipping_address' => $shipping_address,
                    'shipping_method'  => $order_info['shipping_method'],
                    'product'          => $product_data,
                    'comment'          => nl2br($order_info['comment']),

                    'shipping_postcode' => $order_info['shipping_postcode']
                );
```

Now you can use in the template: `{{ order.shipping_postcode }}`